# How to dump Mac address table in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking

Linux is heavily used for networking - then why something so basic as listing the mac address-table in Linux is still a challenge? Why there is no show command to dump mac address table ? I tried searching on internet and could not find a clear solution. Pls help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for the ARP table use

```
ip neighbour show
```

or `ip n` for short

---

for the fdb of a linux bridge (like a switch mac address table)

```
bridge fdb show
```

or `bridge f` for short

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is no "show" command. However, you can get the mac address details via "ipconfig -a" or "arp -a".

Comment: i am not looking for mac addresses. I am looking for mac address table.